# Receive data in ajax call back from server without reloading and update current page. Express 4 and Node

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

I have a form

```
form#form-reflow(action='/', method='post', 
                    onsubmit="docreflow()")
    input#textinp(type="text", name="textinp")
    input#submit(type="submit", name="submit")
```

that runs the following ajax client script to send the form data to Express.

```
function docreflow() {
    $('#form-reflow').on('submit', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        $.post($('#form-reflow').attr( 'action' ),
            {  
                data: $("#textinp").val(),
                headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                dataType: 'text',
                accepts: {
                            text: 'text/plain'
                        },
            })
            .done(function onDone (data) {
                            console.log("returned data is: ");
                            var data = JSON.parse(data).data;
                            console.log(data);
                            $('#form-reflow').html(data);
                        }
            )
            .fail(function onFail(err) {
                $('#form-reflow').html("<p> There Wazza Khold Dey</p>");
            });
    })
}
```

I want the server POST method to not reload the page.

Instead I want to know how can I receive the data on the client back as an html:
this is jade btw.

```
div#ajaxMsg
    p It actually works!
    p Data is "#{data}"
```

from the controller method while it does something like

```
res.render('afterReload.jade', {some data...})
```

The page should not reload instead on ajax done it should
just include that rendered html snippet here:

```
$('#form-reflow').html(data);
```

For eg, consider you would write an AJAX api to New york times 
the NYT api uses a jsonp to sendback with your defined Callback
and I can just include that data in my current page.

Lets say I do a json rendering only. from the server I send the json data

and on success, the function will append that data on client side as I wish.

How can I do a 'No Reload' AJAX server to client response?

Feel free to ask me for further clarity.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123315/retrieving-data-with-jquery-ajax-without-reloading-page)

changing the evt type to change doesn't affect the behaviour. it still reloads the page.

Both the current and POST page controller routes are defined to be **'/'**

**UPDATE**
I have removed the html5 onsubmit event. no need:

```
  form#form-reflow(action='/', method='post')
    input#textinp(type="text", name="textinp")
    input#submit(type="submit", name="submit")
```

**UPDATE #2**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143) does not solve my problem

even if I add a `return false;` at the end of the function call in that script,

the controller function:

```
function ajaxReq(req, res) {

            console.log(req.body);

            if (req.accepts('text')) {
                //#TODO: do something with this to doc reflow instead page reload
                res.json({data: req.body.textinp});
            }
        };
```

still reloads the page.

I disagree with @mccannf for pointing out that its a duplicate.

No it doesn't solve my problem. Try implementing an express app. where you render something at '/' with a form that posts with ajax to server and it should render back an html snippet from, say a .jade/template file, as an html chunk back to the successful ajax call and replace the current html in place of form.

That is the core of my problem.

**UPDATE #3**

I have been able to check [this out](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-partial) and do a rendering but its not doing a partial rendering.
Anyone knows how to use it in express 4 without loading the whole page and 
returning value to ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves my problem and now it is a single working page:

```
script(src="js/scr.js")
```

the view is this and something more:

```
form#form-reflow(action='/scr')
    input#textinp(type="text", name="textinp")
    input#submit(type="submit", name="submit")
```

scr is this without a function wrapper. for eg:

```
$('#form-reflow').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var posting = $.post( $('#form-reflow').attr( 'action' ), 
            {data:$("#textinp").val()
            })
        posting.done(
            function onDone (val) {
                $("#form-reflow").removeAttr('action');
                $("#form-reflow")
                .html("<p> hello baby " + val.data + "</p>");
                });
        return false;
    });
```

the controller is :

```
some_controller = function some_controller(req, res) {


            if (req.accepts(['json', 'jsonp'])) {


                res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                var json_data = {data: req.body.data,
                                };
                res.jsonp(json_data);

            }
        };
app.use('/', some_router);
some_router.post('/scr',some_controller);
```

So this works without rendering to a new page.